# (XAMPP) Linux :MySQL said: Documentation #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, vmware

I am using xampp on VMware and OS is Linux and got heavily stuck while selecting or deleting or anything and dont know why this is happening. I also checked xampp feature are running i.e Mysql, Apache and ProFTPD.

Message shows:

```
Error

    SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

    SELECT `comment`
                   FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info`
                  WHERE db_name     = 'project'
                    AND table_name  = ''
                    AND column_name = '(db_comment)'

    MySQL said: Documentation
    #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine
```

Any idea?? please share

Comment: You need to re-config the phpmyadmin, some default setting is missing

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did small work. I just installed older version i.e 5.6.12-0 and that is running fine.

Link for download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.12/